# Why do I get Unable to create container with image Unable to pull image error pulling image when using multiple Docker hosts?

Tags: docker, terraform

I am trying to perform a simple deployment using terraform (0.12.24), and multiple Docker providers (plugin version 2.7.0). My aim using the terraform template below is to deploy two different containers to two different Docker-enabled hosts.

```
# Configure the Docker provider
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://192.168.1.10:2375/"
}

provider "docker" {
  alias = "worker"
  host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/"
}

# Create a container
resource "docker_container" "hello" {
  image = docker_image.world.latest
  name  = "hello"
}

resource "docker_container" "test" {
  provider = docker.worker
  image = docker_image.world.latest
  name  = "test"
}

resource "docker_image" "world" {
  name = "hello-world:latest"
}
```

The `docker` command runs successfully without root privileges. The Docker daemons of both machines 192.168.1.10 and 127.0.0.1 listen on 2375, are reachable from the host machine and can respond to direct Docker REST API calls (create,pull etc.) performed with curl. Manually pulling images also works in both hosts, and I did that to be sure that the latest `hello-world` image exists in both.

However, the terraform deployment (terraform apply) fails with the following error:

```
docker_container.hello: Creating...
docker_container.test: Creating...
docker_container.hello: Creation complete after 1s [id=77e515b4269aed255d4becac61f40d38e09838cdf8285294bf51f3c7cddbf2bf]

Error: Unable to create container with image sha256:a29f45ccde2ac0bde957b1277b1501f471960c8ca49f1588c6c885941640ae60: Unable to pull image sha256:a29f45ccde2ac0bde957b1277b1501f471960c8ca49f1588c6c885941640ae60: error pulling image sha256:a29f45ccde2ac0bde957b1277b1501f471960c8ca49f1588c6c885941640ae60: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for sha256, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

  on test.tf line 17, in resource "docker_container" "test":
  17: resource "docker_container" "test" {
```

Why do I get Unable to create container with image Unable to pull image error pulling image when using multiple Docker hosts?

Comment: You probably need to do the `docker pull` (`docker_image` resource) on both systems (providers).  But, turn off remote Docker daemon access on port 2375, _now_, and use the Docker provider's ssh transport: anyone who can reach that port can trivially root the host, where the ssh transport has encryption and authorization controls.

Comment: Thank you for replying! You are right about the possibility of fraudulent access, but this is considered an 'isolated' network for the purposes of this attempt. For the record, using the ssh transport makes no difference as the same error comes up

Comment: You need to pull the image on both hosts that you want to run the containers on. Adding another `docker_image` resource but with the `docker.worker` provider and having that be the resource that the other container is dependent on should fix this.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Could you please elaborate on this solution? I tried adding a second resource 
```resource "docker_image" "world2" {
  name = "hello-world:latest"
}```, and changed the image reference in the second container to use it (`docker_image.world2.latest`) but the same error occurs. I have also pulled both containers in both nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some problems with the template which was originally used in the question.
Firstly, short-running hello-world containers are used, which leads to at least one of the services exiting with an error message by Terraform.
Then, with the important help of @Alain O'Dea (see relevant answer and comments) I created the following modified template, which works and accomplishes my goal.

```
# Configure the Docker provider
provider "docker" {
  host = "tcp://192.168.1.10:2375/"
}

provider "docker" {
  alias = "worker"
  host = "tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/"
}

# Create a container
resource "docker_container" "hello" {
  image = docker_image.world.latest
  name  = "hello"
}

resource "docker_container" "test" {
  provider = docker.worker
  image = docker_image.world_image.latest
  name  = "test"
}

resource "docker_image" "world" {
  name = "prom/prometheus:latest"
}

resource "docker_image" "world_image" {
  provider = docker.worker
  name = "nextcloud:latest"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**docker_container.test** references **docker_image.world**, but they use different providers (**default** and **docker.worker**):

```
resource "docker_container" "test" {
  provider = docker.worker
  image = docker_image.world.latest
  name  = "test"
}

resource "docker_image" "world" {
  name = "hello-world:latest"
}
```

This is fatal as **docker_image.world** uses provided **default** which runs the **docker pull** on **tcp://192.168.1.10:2375/** (not on **tcp://127.0.0.1:2375/**).

This can be fixed by creating a **docker_image** using provider **docker.world_worker** to match **docker_container.test** as follows:

```
resource "docker_container" "test" {
  provider = docker.world_worker
  image = docker_image.world.latest
  name  = "test"
}

resource "docker_image" "world_worker" {
  provider = docker.world_worker
  name = "hello-world:latest"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I changed the 'test' `docker_container` resource, and also tried either adding a new 'world_worker' docker image resource, or replacing the existing 'worker' resource to match what you provided. I now though get two different errors - could you please provide the complete amended terraform template?

Comment: 1st Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with docker_image.world_worker its original provider configuration at
provider.docker.world_worker is required, but it has been removed. This occurs
when a provider configuration is removed while objects created by that
provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to
destroy docker_image.world_worker, after which you can remove the provider
configuration again.

Comment: 2nd Error: Provider configuration not present

To work with docker_container.test its original provider configuration at
provider.docker.world_worker is required, but it has been removed. This occurs
when a provider configuration is removed while objects created by that
provider still exist in the state. Re-add the provider configuration to
destroy docker_container.test, after which you can remove the provider
configuration again.

Comment: The code snippet above isn't a replacement for your whole module, it's a recommended modification. You need to keep your original source intact (particularly including providers) and change **image** on **docker_container.test** and add **docker_image.world_worker** as an additional resource. That should resolve the errors.